# Can the size be set on Access 2010 number fields?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am working on a project for class and it includes the creation of some Access 2010 tables and DB.  The instructor is requesting specific sizes for Long Integer fields.  I understand how to set this for numbers in SQL but not in access.  It looks like the size can be set for Text but not for Number so I was wondering if there is a way to set the size on these fields in Access 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set validation rules, for example:

```
< 9999
```

[image: Validation rule]

In MS Access 2010 and on, you can also use [data macros](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx).

Finally, you can set a [constraint through DDL and VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177889(v=office.12).aspx) (see my notes at the end of the article.)

Comment: Remou thank you.  I would not have thought about using validation rules.  Again thanks for the insight and quick reply.  Back to work I go hehe.